# CreateQueryBuilder to find a string in an array?

Tags: orm, doctrine, repository, createquery

I want to find if a `$work (string)` exist in `Works (array)`, how can I write the request?

```
public function findByProject($project, $work)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->andWhere('p.project_type = :project')
        ->andWhere('p.works = :work')
        ->setParameter('project', $project)
        ->setParameter('work', $work)
        ->orderBy('p.id', 'ASC')
        //->setMaxResults(10)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public function findByProject($project, $work)

```
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->andWhere('p.project_type = :project')
        ->andWhere('p.works LIKE :work')
        ->setParameter('project', $project)
        ->setParameter('work', '%'.$work.'%')
        ->orderBy('p.id', 'ASC')
        //->setMaxResults(10)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```